# How do I move to the next & back from dialog box & return to Main Menu properly after selection

Tags: java, menu, program-entry-point, joptionpane

I have 3 questions. I appreciate if advise me how to resolve them.

My App start off with a main menu. When I insert 1 it will display the 1st game details. When I insert "FW" into the dialog box, it will bring me to the next game details. A "BK" will bring me back to the previous game details.

Q1. My problem is the app bring me to the next game details even when i insert the wrong alphabet command. How do I ensure only the right command is obey?

Q2. The app would not bring me back to the previous game menu. Did I miss out something here?

Q3. And how do I need to code to get back to the main menu? I have copy the main menu. But when I try to use the app again. It terminates itself instead.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class gamelist {
public static void main(String args[]){

ArrayList<String> sku = new ArrayList<String> ();
sku.add("1");
sku.add("2");
sku.add("3");
sku.add("4");


ArrayList<String> games = new ArrayList<String>();
games.add("Swimming");
games.add("Running");
games.add("Cycling");
games.add("Basketball");

String mainMenu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Main Menu\n 1." +
        " Display Each Game\n 2. Quit");

        int selectOption = Integer.parseInt(mainMenu);

        switch (selectOption){
        case 1:
            // Display 1st game
            String input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, sku.get(0) + " " + games.get(0) + "\n\n" +
                    "Enter FW for Next "  + "\n" +
                    "Enter BK for Back"  + "\n" +
                    "Enter M to return to Main Menu."  + "\n");


            if (input1.equals("FW")){
                for ( int i=1;  i < sku.size(); i++){
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,sku.get(i) + " " + games.get(i) + "\n\n" +
                            "Enter FW for Next "  + "\n" +
                            "Enter BK for Back"  + "\n" +
                            "Enter M to return to Main Menu."  + "\n");
                }
            }
                else if( input1.equals("BK")){

                for ( int j=1;  j < sku.size(); j--) {
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,sku.get(j) + " " + games.get(j) +"\n\n" +
                    "Enter FW for Next "  + "\n" +
                    "Enter BK for Back"  + "\n" +
                    "Enter M to return to Main Menu."  + "\n");

                        }
                }

                else if( input1.equals("M"))
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Main Menu\n 1." +
                            " Display Each Game\n 2. Quit");

                        break;

        default:

              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye");
              System.exit(0);
              break;

    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer to only Q3.

Don't write `break;` in amin menu case...